# Removing rows when date prior today -

Tags: vba, loops, date, rows

I'm struggling with the following: I want to delete rows for which date (column C) is prior than today. My code should work (according to the web) but it doesn't and moreover, it's super slow.. Here is a part of it:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow     
    If Cells(i, "C").Value < Date Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete    
Next i
```

Instead of putting "C", I could put 3, but doesn't change anything. I've tried to add the End If (before the next i), but not necessary apparently. Maybe the Date is not the right format..

What's wrong with this code ?

Great thanks for your help :)

Comment: what is it doing that it shouldn't? `Not Working` is not descriptive enough.  Also try looping backwards: `For i = LastRow to 2 Step -1`

Comment: Not working means the rows with date prior than today were not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the auto-filter capabilities of Excel in your favor. Filter the range by your criteria to delete the matching rows:

```
  With Range("C1:C" & lastrow)
    .AutoFilter 1, "<" & CLng(Date)
    .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
  End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Works really great and fast :)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to step backwards when deleting rows and verify that it is actually a date  in the cell. To see what it's doing, set a breakpoint on the first line and use F8 to step through it. Also verify the value of LastRow is getting set to the correct value.

```
For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If IsDate(Cells(i, "C").Value) then
        If Cells(i, "C").Value < Date Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: you also may want to convert the cell to an actual date value... 

`CVDate(Cells(i, "C").Value) < Date`

Comment: Thanks for your answer braX. I've just put your code and it works. But it's extremely slow when computing (I have 11 000 rows, maybe why, but strange because faster for bigger file but for other formulas (not if)). I didn't put the convert code, since the format is date (right click on Excel). Will the conversion make it faster? I didn't get where to set a breakpoint : in the file or in the code ? Thanks :)

Comment: You can disable screen updates while it processes.

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

and then turn it back on when you are done.